# How to substring a column value and how to group by base on the column in cassandra 2.1.8?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I need to get some part of the cassandra column,

for example:
column value is 1435968000_2592000_MK_897654123

I need to get 1435968000 and 2592000 separately,

and need to apply where condition on 1435968000 and 'group by' condition on 2592000

I have Cassandra 2.18 database.
please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: In Cassandra you can only filter with primary key column. You have to design your schema in that way.

Comment: Hi Ashraful, can I substring 1435968000 from 1435968000_2592000_MK_897654123

Comment: No, there is no built in way. you have to do it from the application layer